# Can't find MySql port 3306

Tags: mysql, database, localhost

I am unable to create a localhost MySql database, I am getting an error saying "connection refused".

I tried to debug the same by:

- Creating new inbound as well as outbound rule in the firewall setting for port 3306.
- I have also checked my command prompt for the port 3306 by typing the command 'netstat -an', but it does not even show that port 3306 exists.
- And when I typed the command 'netstat -an | grep -i listen | grep -E 3306' it says that grep is not recognized.

Comment: first check if the service is running, in the properties of the service the parameters that is used so you know where to find the my.ini and the error log usually under C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to edit your `my.cnf` file and make sure you have the port set as in the following line:

`port = 3360`

Comment: I don't have any file named `my.cnf` in my MySql Workbench folder

Comment: The my.cnf file is for the mysql server, not the workbench client.